# Eclipse 2021 Maven Spring Junit Build Failure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-test

I'm trying to use Eclipse-2021-03. What built under maven fine with Eclipse-Neon now fails. In Eclipse-2021-03, maven has resolved this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This can be seen in the image below, but I'm getting the errors, "The import org.springframework.test cannot be resolved":

[image]

Just can't figure out why. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here; I was looking for an answer in the wrong place. The salient indicator is the grey icon next to the maven jar it seems: [Eclipse Maven dependency jar grayed out, can't import classes from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372670/eclipse-maven-dependency-jar-grayed-out-cant-import-classes-from-it).